# how can I run this program without crashing in gtk?

Tags: c, gtk

I want to have the both 'for loop' and my 'gtk window' in this program.
as you know, after the loop end the gtk window will be open.but I wan to have them at the same time.

How can I do this?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i;
  GtkWidget *window;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "markup label");
    getchar();
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",i);
      getchar();

    }
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 100);

  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, What about threads:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void * go(void *threadid)
{

    int i;
    for(i=1;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    GtkWidget *window;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "markup label");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 100);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
                     G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    pthread_t t;
    int rc = pthread_create(&t , NULL , go ,NULL);
    if (rc){
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }

    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

to compile :

```
gcc -Wall -g  main.c -o my_gtk `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

tested on lubuntu with gtk 3.